# Deleting lines between two characters using sed

Tags: sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I have multiple datasets in txt format which have a predictable content. I am trying to remove the first set of lines. The first line starts with `>*chromosome` and I want to delete everything until `>*plasmid`. I can either tell it to delete everything from `>` until it encounters it again or delete everything between the first `>` and the second `>`. I have been trying something like this:

```
sed -i.bak '/>/,/^\>*$/{d}' file.txt
```

This did not work the original code I found was:

```
sed -i.bak '/>/,/^\s*$/{d}' file.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts, could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question for better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: You know the first line so you use its address rather than a regexp i.e. 1. You know how to remove up to a regexp i.e `address,/regexp/d` Now you want to keep the line that is identified by the regexp. i.e. `/regexp/p`. Put it all together( in the right order)!

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{^>chromosome.*(?=^>plasmid)}{}sm' in.fasta
```

EXAMPLE:

```
# Create example input file:

cat > in.fasta <<EOF
>foo
TCGA
>chromosome
ACGT
>plasmid
CGTA
EOF

perl -0777 -pe 's{^>chromosome.*(?=^>plasmid)}{}sm' in.fasta > out.fasta
```

Output in `out.fasta`:

```
>foo
TCGA
>plasmid
CGTA
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-0777` : Slurp files whole.

The regex uses these modifiers:

`/m` : Allow multiline matches.
`/s` : Allow `.` to match a newline.

`^>chromosome.*(?=^>plasmid)` : Regex that matches `>chromosome` starts starts at the beginning of the line, followed by 0 or more characters, and ending right at (but not including) the match to `>plasmid` at the beginning of the line. The expression `(?=PATTERN)` is zero-length positive lookahead.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)